# Installing .net framework 3.5

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-3.5

When I am installing SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 8.1 there was an error saying download and install .net framework 3.5 (including 2.0 and 1.0)

And when I'm trying to install .net framework 3.5 from command prompt with following command,

```
C:\Windows\system32>DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All 
                         /Limit Access /Source:c:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

I got the error

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
>   Version: 6.3.9600.16384
>
> Image Version: 6.3.9600.16384
>
> Enabling feature(s)
>   [===========================65.8%======                    ]
>
> Error: 0x800f081f
>
> The source files could not be found.
>
> Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

Please help me.......

Comment: /Source: should point to the Sources/sxs folder on the installation media not c:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log. See also Powershell option at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34537239/17373

Answer (score 1):

.NET framework 3.5 and 4.5 are parts of windows 8. so you have to add it using the windows features as described below :
go to your `control panel` -> `Programs and features` -> `Turn windows features on or off`
tick the check box `.NET framework 3.5`

Answer (score 0):

some time the two KB not show up. the only way to uninstall those two KB is download tools from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3005628
after remove those two KB. the 0x800f081f will gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to update with latest patches (optionals also) the Operating System.

Then I added the W2012 dvd to disk D

And finally run the command (as administrator):

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```