# .NET framework error x800f081f

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8.1, failed-installation

I have Windows 8.1 64-bit installed on my PC and when i install .net 3.5 it's showing this error

```
    Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required t
o restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

I have found various solutions online which tells me to uninstall some updates but I don't have any of these updates installed on my system.

PS: Files are not corrupted as I have checked it by installing .net on another system.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2734782

Comment: I have edited the group policy, still the same error

Comment: use the provided DISM command

Comment: this is the error when i used the DISM command

Comment: copy the folders C:\windows\logs\CBS and C:\windows\logs\DISM to your desktop, zip them to a 1 zip, upload the zip (Onedrive), create a share link and paste it here.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2F0B1E4F1FD42064!138&authkey=!AH5L0uZvC_x0mqc&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: what is your native installed language? Have you added the en-us MUI later?

Comment: My native installed language is en-US.I have not installed any languages later

Comment: check the paragraph about x0800f081f in the KB article. Copy the Sxs folder to C:\ and point to this folder on C: when using DISM. Also try a different ISO/DVD

Comment: fixed the issue by removing some more updates and a startup cleaning command.
Thanks Anyways.

Comment: post as answer which updates you removed and which cleanup command you've used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point it to the Sources\sxs folder on the installation media. Powershell example from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34537239/17373):

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName NetFx3 -Source e:\Sources\sxs

In the last command -Source e:\Sources\sxs is only required if the feature needs to reference the installation media for source files (usually to fix Error: 0x800f081f The source files could not be found). The .NET Framework version 3.5 seems to be the only feature that requires that for the client OS, but there are many others on the Server OS that require referencing the installation media for sources.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of solution over web for this like standalone installer of .net framework 3.5. I have tried all but nothing worked for me. How I have finally solved the issue is with windows CD, and run a commend in commend bar.

**Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:E:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess**

where E: is the path of CD which can be some other drive for other  user. this hardly take 5 min and after completion you go and check the feature you'll will find it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I had tried that using Windows 10 and got the same error. My workaround is using VirtualBox, create a Windows 7 VM, and install any application that use Net 3.5 there. You can also dual-boot your existing computer with Windows 7, too. Using Windows 8 (might) also better.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps might help to allow Windows Update and feature installation(Net 3.5) on Windows server:

```
1. Type Win+R-> type gpedit.msc -> Administrative Templates -> System
   ->  Specify settings for optional component installation and component 
   repair -> 
   Enabled and mark Download repair content(WSUS)
2. Configure Automatic Updates : Run regedit.exe and go to 
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate->AU. 
   Change the value of UseWUServer to 0.
3. On command prompt run Netsh: netsh.exe and  setting proxy server: 
    winhttp set proxy proxyservername:portnumber
4. Open command prompt. Stop and then start Windows update:     
    net stop "Windows Update"   
    net start "Windows Update"
```

[Reference for setting  proxy server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/900935/how-the-windows-update-client-determines-which-proxy-server-to-use-to)