# Automating installation of IIS

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, automation

The goal is to automate enabling of IIS on a new Windows Workstation, like Windows 10, for a .NET development environment. I realize that Powershell scripts can be written to do something like this but I don't know where to start.

I realize I could easily go into Control Panel and enable the service there  however it seems more efficient to just run a script to do this.

What would an example script look like that would be run in Powershell to enable IIS?

Comment: Why not Google? That's where to start, not here.

Comment: I've been using Google for days/weeks. Powershell scripts are not common for this type of task and that baffles me. Most articles reference using Powershell itself instead of a script.

Comment: What's the difference between a "Powershell script" and "Powershell itself"?

Comment: @jscott https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh551144.aspx

Comment: @micah really? Why I easily find this? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205467(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: @LexLi The article you point to says nothing about how to use these commands in a script, best practices on formatting the scripting language, the order in which tasks should be executed, etc. It's a decent reference for people who want to learn how to use commands in the Powershell console itself. I need a bit more instruction than this as I don't come from the Microsoft world of programming.

Comment: I assume now you are facing a how-to question for PowerShell, not for IIS or Windows. Use cmdlet in PowerShell scripts are so obvious. BTW, how-to questions (that ask for tutorials) are not for SO, and I cast my vote to close.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Server OS's**

On Windows Server you could run the following command to automate installation of IIS:

```
#-LogPath can be added if you want a log to be created of the installation
#-Restart can be added if you want to auto restart after installation
Install-WindowsFeature -ComputerName SomePCHere -Name Web-Server
```

Here are the names of the IIS features from PowerShell's point of view:

```
Display Name                                            Name                 
------------                                            ----                      
    [ ] Web Application Proxy                           Web-Application-Proxy          
[ ] Web Server (IIS)                                    Web-Server                     
    [ ] Web Server                                      Web-WebServer                  
        [ ] Common HTTP Features                        Web-Common-Http                
            [ ] Default Document                        Web-Default-Doc                
            [ ] Directory Browsing                      Web-Dir-Browsing               
            [ ] HTTP Errors                             Web-Http-Errors                
            [ ] Static Content                          Web-Static-Content             
            [ ] HTTP Redirection                        Web-Http-Redirect              
            [ ] WebDAV Publishing                       Web-DAV-Publishing             
        [ ] Health and Diagnostics                      Web-Health                     
            [ ] HTTP Logging                            Web-Http-Logging               
            [ ] Custom Logging                          Web-Custom-Logging             
            [ ] Logging Tools                           Web-Log-Libraries              
            [ ] ODBC Logging                            Web-ODBC-Logging               
            [ ] Request Monitor                         Web-Request-Monitor            
            [ ] Tracing                                 Web-Http-Tracing               
        [ ] Performance                                 Web-Performance                
            [ ] Static Content Compression              Web-Stat-Compression           
            [ ] Dynamic Content Compression             Web-Dyn-Compression            
        [ ] Security                                    Web-Security                   
            [ ] Request Filtering                       Web-Filtering                  
            [ ] Basic Authentication                    Web-Basic-Auth                 
            [ ] Centralized SSL Certificate Support     Web-CertProvider               
            [ ] Client Certificate Mapping Authentic... Web-Client-Auth                
            [ ] Digest Authentication                   Web-Digest-Auth                
            [ ] IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authe... Web-Cert-Auth                  
            [ ] IP and Domain Restrictions              Web-IP-Security                
            [ ] URL Authorization                       Web-Url-Auth                   
            [ ] Windows Authentication                  Web-Windows-Auth               
        [ ] Application Development                     Web-App-Dev                    
            [ ] .NET Extensibility 3.5                  Web-Net-Ext                    
            [ ] .NET Extensibility 4.5                  Web-Net-Ext45                  
            [ ] Application Initialization              Web-AppInit                    
            [ ] ASP                                     Web-ASP                        
            [ ] ASP.NET 3.5                             Web-Asp-Net                    
            [ ] ASP.NET 4.5                             Web-Asp-Net45                  
            [ ] CGI                                     Web-CGI                        
            [ ] ISAPI Extensions                        Web-ISAPI-Ext                  
            [ ] ISAPI Filters                           Web-ISAPI-Filter               
            [ ] Server Side Includes                    Web-Includes                   
            [ ] WebSocket Protocol                      Web-WebSockets                 
    [ ] FTP Server                                      Web-Ftp-Server                 
        [ ] FTP Service                                 Web-Ftp-Service                
        [ ] FTP Extensibility                           Web-Ftp-Ext                    
    [ ] Management Tools                                Web-Mgmt-Tools                 
        [ ] IIS Management Console                      Web-Mgmt-Console               
        [ ] IIS 6 Management Compatibility              Web-Mgmt-Compat                
            [ ] IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility            Web-Metabase                   
            [ ] IIS 6 Management Console                Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console          
            [ ] IIS 6 Scripting Tools                   Web-Lgcy-Scripting             
            [ ] IIS 6 WMI Compatibility                 Web-WMI                        
        [ ] IIS Management Scripts and Tools            Web-Scripting-Tools            
        [ ] Management Service                          Web-Mgmt-Service               
[ ] IIS Hostable Web Core                               Web-WHC
```

Separate each feature you wish to install by a comma on the "Name" parameter. Example:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -ComputerName SomePCHere -Name Web-Server, Web-Mgmt-Tools, Web-Security
```

**Clients OS's**

On Windows 8.1+ you can use the `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature` and `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` to install IIS.

By running the following you can get the names of the IIS features from PowerShell's point of view:

```
PS C:\> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online | Where {$_.FeatureName -like 'IIS*'} | Sort FeatureName | Format-Table

FeatureName                                   State
-----------                                   -----
IIS-ApplicationDevelopment                 Disabled
IIS-ApplicationInit                        Disabled
IIS-ASP                                    Disabled
IIS-ASPNET                                 Disabled
IIS-ASPNET45                               Disabled
IIS-BasicAuthentication                    Disabled
IIS-CertProvider                           Disabled
IIS-CGI                                    Disabled
IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication Disabled
IIS-CommonHttpFeatures                     Disabled
IIS-CustomLogging                          Disabled
IIS-DefaultDocument                        Disabled
IIS-DigestAuthentication                   Disabled
IIS-DirectoryBrowsing                      Disabled
IIS-FTPExtensibility                       Disabled
IIS-FTPServer                              Disabled
IIS-FTPSvc                                 Disabled
IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics                   Disabled
IIS-HostableWebCore                        Disabled
IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic                 Disabled
IIS-HttpCompressionStatic                  Disabled
IIS-HttpErrors                             Disabled
IIS-HttpLogging                            Disabled
IIS-HttpRedirect                           Disabled
IIS-HttpTracing                            Disabled
IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility            Disabled
IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication    Disabled
IIS-IPSecurity                             Disabled
IIS-ISAPIExtensions                        Disabled
IIS-ISAPIFilter                            Disabled
IIS-LegacyScripts                          Disabled
IIS-LegacySnapIn                           Disabled
IIS-LoggingLibraries                       Disabled
IIS-ManagementConsole                      Disabled
IIS-ManagementScriptingTools               Disabled
IIS-ManagementService                      Disabled
IIS-Metabase                               Disabled
IIS-NetFxExtensibility                     Disabled
IIS-NetFxExtensibility45                   Disabled
IIS-ODBCLogging                            Disabled
IIS-Performance                            Disabled
IIS-RequestFiltering                       Disabled
IIS-RequestMonitor                         Disabled
IIS-Security                               Disabled
IIS-ServerSideIncludes                     Disabled
IIS-StaticContent                          Disabled
IIS-URLAuthorization                       Disabled
IIS-WebDAV                                 Disabled
IIS-WebServer                              Disabled
IIS-WebServerManagementTools               Disabled
IIS-WebServerRole                          Disabled
IIS-WebSockets                             Disabled
IIS-WindowsAuthentication                  Disabled
IIS-WMICompatibility                       Disabled
```

Similar to windows server, you can install the features above by running the following or something similar (you can install multiple features by using a comma to separate the values on the FeatureName parameter :

```
#you can add -NoRestart to prevent automatic restarting (if required)
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Webserver
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: I assume this line of code above will also run on Windows 7/8/10, right? After running the `.ps1`, running as Admin, that I created with `Install-WindowsFeature -ComputerName SomePCHere -Name Web-Server, Web-Mgmt-Tools, Web-Security`, I go to the Windows Features window in Control Panel > Programs and Features and it doesn't show IIS as installed/enabled. Is there something else I should be doing to make this work on regular Windows?

Comment: My initial answer was for Windows server only. I just edited and added a section for client OS's. The client OS part will only work on Windows 8.1+.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>See [Tyler Helder's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893187/45375) for the full list of IIS-related features and more information about the parameters of the [`Install-WindowsFeature`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205467(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet; the focus of *this* answer is more conceptual.</sup>

There's a good chance that the **`ServerManager` PowerShell module** comes preinstalled with your Windows *server* OS (W2K8R2+; note that *client* OSs [require a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34537239/45375)):

If so, you can **install IIS as follows**:

- Open an *elevated* PowerShell console (Run as Administrator)
- Run `Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server`

**`Add-WindowsFeature`, present since W2K8R2, was renamed to `Install-WindowsFeature`** in W2K12R2, but `Add-WindowsFeature` was retained as an *alias*, so it works in both versions.

To **list *all* server features and their *installation status*, run `Get-WindowsFeature`.**

Note that it is **the values from the `Name` column that must be provided as arguments to the `Add-WindowsFeature` / `Install-WindowsFeature` cmdlets**, whereas the `DisplayName column` often contains the keyword of interest.

Case in point: To discover all features whose display name contains "IIS" - and thereby discover that the name of the IIS feature is `Web-Server` - run (PSv3+):

```
Get-WindowsFeature | ? DisplayName -like *IIS*
```